# Amazon MWS GetReport error

Tags: php, amazon-mws

I was trying to get the information regarding the Product catalog via _GET_WEBSTORE_PRODUCT_CATALOG_ ReportType. I was succesfull in submitting the report request and even it was processed and even the processing status was DONE and generated id was also collected. But when I try to get the report via the Action: GetReport it gives an Market place is not sent, even though the market place was mentioned. Below is the sample of codes and I m not using any of the PHP client library....

Code Sample

```
<?php

require 'config.php';    
$param = array(
    'AWSAccessKeyId'=> AWS_KEY,
    'Action'=>'GetReport',

    'ReportId'=>'513798174016724',
    'Merchant'=> MERCHANT_ID,
    'SignatureMethod' => "HmacSHA256",
    'SignatureVersion'=> "2",
    'Timestamp'=> gmdate("Y-m-d\TH:i:s.\\0\\0\\0\\Z", time()),
    'Version' => "2009-01-01",
    'Marketplace'=>MARKETPLACE
);
$secret = AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
$url = array();
foreach ($param as $key => $val) {
    $key = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($key));
    $val = str_replace("%7E", "~", rawurlencode($val));
    $url[] = "{$key}={$val}";
}    
sort($url);
$arr   = implode('&', $url);
$sign  = 'POST' . "\n";
$sign .= 'mws.amazonservices.com' . "\n";
$sign .= '/' . "\n";
$sign .= $arr;    
$signature = hash_hmac("sha256", $sign, $secret, true);
$signature = urlencode(base64_encode($signature));    
$link  = "https://mws.amazonservices.com/?";
$link .= $arr . "&Signature=" . $signature;
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(

    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $link,
    CURLOPT_POST => 1,

    )
);  

$resp1 = curl_exec($curl);    
curl_close($curl);    
print_r($resp1);
```

And error Sample
**Please indicate a marketplace for which the report is required.**
Is there anything I am missing... or where I have mistyped something ...
Thanks for the solution in advance..

Comment: Mind you that this report is only if you have a web-store on amazon not normal amazon seller account. And also in this link (http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/reports/Reports_ReportType.html) it says Note: If you have multiple marketplaces, the Comparison Shopping Engine and Google Merchant Center Product feeds are only generated for the primary marketplace associated with your account. You must include the primary marketplace identifier in the MarketplaceIdList request parameter when you specify either the comparisonshoppingenginefeed or googlemerchantcenterproductfeed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing to these

```
$request = new MarketplaceWebService_Model_RequestReportRequest();

$marketplaceIdArray = array("Id" => array($marketplace_id));
$request->setMarketplaceIdList($marketplaceIdArray);
$request->setMerchant($merchant_id);
$request->setReportType($this->report_type);
```